# How to create magical labeling for a rooted binary tree

Tags: tree, binary

The sequence {0,1,...,−1} can be used to index the  nodes of a rooted complete binary tree (in top to bottom, left to right order).

A *labelling* or *permutation*  is a mapping that assigns a label  ∈ {0,...,−1} to each vertex  ∀  ∈ {0,...,−1}, resulting in distinct, integer labels for various nodes. A labelling  is called *magical* if it satisfies the following condition:

If we assign to each edge (, ) of the tree the label |−|, i.e. the absolute value of the difference between the labels of nodes  and , then all edge labels must be distinct.

#### Example

For number of nodes  = 5, we can find labeling  = [0,4,2,1,3] as a solution, which can be represented as follows (values are labels):

```
              0
             / \
            4   2
           / \
          1   3
```

The absolute differences on the edges can be depicted as follows:

```
              *
             4 2
            *   *
           3 1
          *   *
```

... and they are unique.

How should I design an algorithm that can find a labeling that has this property?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The ask is to create a binary tree of n nodes such that each of the nodes are distinct and can have values between 0 to n-1.  The tree would be called to have a magical labelling if the following condition is satisfied : each edge(i,j) can be assigned a value of |p[i]¡ p[ j]|  (i.e the absolute difference between the node i and node j) . The edge values must also be distinct for the entire tree.  Consider for n = 5, the tree nodes are [0,4,2,1,3]  written in the natural order (top to bottom, left to right). Then the edge labellings will be [4,2,3,1] .

Comment: Your question spoke of "full binary tree", but that is wrong. You mean "complete binary tree". Your question also had some unreadable characters. I overhauled it. Please verify.

Comment: Yes, I need a complete binary tree.

Comment: Too bad this question is getting so little attention :/